# sorting custom object array on two fields

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, custom-object

I'm sorting an array of custom objects (`ListData[]`) on two fields. I want it to be sorted by theme, and them by name. I thought i made a nice comparator in the custom object class and that i could use `Arrays.sort(ld)` to make my code working and sorting my array. But apparently im doing something wrong...

my custom object:

```
   public class ListData implements Comparable<ListData>{
public int venueID;
public String name;
public String photoUrl;
public String tip;
public String theme;
@Override
public int compareTo(ListData ld0) {
    return this.venueID- ld0.venueID;
}

public static Comparator<ListData> ListDataThemeAndNameComparator = new Comparator<ListData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ListData ld1, ListData ld2) {

        String compareTheme1 = ld1.theme.toUpperCase();
        String compareTheme2= ld2.theme.toUpperCase();
        String compareName1 = ld1.name.toUpperCase();
        String compareName2= ld2.name.toUpperCase();

        //ascending
        int comp = compareTheme1.compareTo(compareTheme2); // comp themes
        if(comp==0){ // same theme
            comp= compareName1.compareTo(compareName2); // compare names 
        }
        return comp;
        }
};


}
```

And in my main activity i have:

```
 ListData ld[]= new ListData[jsonResponse.size()];
(some code filling my ListData array)
 Arrays.sort(ld, ListData.ListDataThemeAndNameComparator); // compare by theme and then by name
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

**I edited my code** But still it fails, now on a nullpointerexception on the `compareTheme1 = ld1.theme.toUpperCase();`. But i am sure my array is not empty, i logged it the line before sorting it and its filled with about 500 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListData` object should implements `Comparable` not `Comparator` interface.

`EDIT:`

To make things clear, you can sort an `array` by `Array.sort()`. To make custom sort, you can specify your comparator in `Array.sort()`, if you don't do that, array will be sorted in natural order which you can define by implementing `Comparable` interface. So you have two options how to custom sort:

- by using custom comparator and specifying it in `Array.sort()`
- by implementing `Comparable` interface to your items

I would suggest you to go with implementing `Comparable`. You save memory by not creating new comparator objects and `Comparator` is useful if you are comparing objects of different types which is not your case.

Comment: I edited my code, and now i have an other error(explained in my question). Thank you for your contribution, but only changing comparator to comparable (and ofcourse imports etc) isn't solving my problem.

Comment: Your array may not be empty, but it seems that some of your elements have not theme field initialized. Check theme and name for null.

Comment: You are right. I had some empty fields at the end of the array, because i declared a to big array. Im changing it to arraylist, but when i used the correct number it worked.